# Artifactory.createClient() throws exception for JFrog Artifactory due to no method signature

Tags: java, groovy, artifactory, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I'm getting the following error when I try to instantiate the Artifactory client.

```
Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClient.create(artifactoryUrl, "", "");
```

Whenever i run my code independently in a main function , it doesnt throw an exception and works properly. But when i run it in a MVC architecture (WebApp) it stops working and throws the following error :

No signature of method: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class) values: [interface org.jfrog.artifactory.client.model.Repository, interface org.jfrog.artifactory.client.impl.jackson.RepositoryMixIn]

And I get the error stack trace below when it executes. I have done extensive research on this issue, and I have not found anyone with a similar error except for the ones referenced in this issue: https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java/issues/85

The above issue was because of wrong dependencies. I'm getting the 2.4.6 version of the artifactory client and the jackson libraries as well.

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixIn() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class) values: [interface org.jfrog.artifactory.client.model.Repository, interface org.jfrog.artifactory.client.impl.jackson.RepositoryMixIn]
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.jfrog.artifactory.client.impl.ArtifactoryImpl.(ArtifactoryImpl.groovy:46)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
>   14:04:21,684 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
>   14:04:21,692 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
>   14:04:21,692 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
>   14:04:21,692 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient.create(ArtifactoryClient.groovy:95)
>   14:04:21,693 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.jfrog.artifactory.client.ArtifactoryClient.create(ArtifactoryClient.groovy)
>   14:04:21,693 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at com.xyz.abc.utils.WGArtifactoryUtils.getFiles(WGArtifactoryUtils.java:41)
>   14:04:21,693 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at com.xyz.abc.lakshya.controllers.ListPlController.findFilesFromArtifactory(ListPlController.java:196)
>   14:04:21,693 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   14:04:21,694 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,695 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,695 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,695 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
>   14:04:21,696 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>   14:04:21,696 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   14:04:21,696 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
>   14:04:21,696 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
>   14:04:21,697 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>   14:04:21,697 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
>   14:04:21,697 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>   14:04:21,698 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>   14:04:21,698 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
>   14:04:21,698 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>   14:04:21,699 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>   14:04:21,699 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   14:04:21,699 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
>   14:04:21,699 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
>   14:04:21,699 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at com.adobe.jobcloud.spring.security.filters.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:65)
>   14:04:21,699 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at com.adobe.jobcloud.ws.security.filters.UiResponseFilter.doFilterInternal(UiResponseFilter.java:55)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   14:04:21,700 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   14:04:21,701 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,701 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   14:04:21,701 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,701 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   14:04:21,701 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,702 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   14:04:21,702 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,702 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>   14:04:21,702 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,703 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   14:04:21,703 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,703 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   14:04:21,703 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,704 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>   14:04:21,704 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,704 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>   14:04:21,704 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,705 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>   14:04:21,705 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   14:04:21,705 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,705 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   14:04:21,705 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   14:04:21,706 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   14:04:21,706 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   14:04:21,706 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>   14:04:21,706 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>   14:04:21,706 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>   14:04:21,707 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
>   14:04:21,707 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
>   14:04:21,707 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   14:04:21,707 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   14:04:21,709 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>   14:04:21,709 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   14:04:21,709 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   14:04:21,710 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>   14:04:21,710 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   14:04:21,711 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>   14:04:21,711 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>   14:04:21,716 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   14:04:21,716 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   14:04:21,716 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   14:04:21,717 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   14:04:21,719 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>   14:04:21,719 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   14:04:21,719 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   14:04:21,719 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>   14:04:21,719 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
>   14:04:21,719 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
>   14:04:21,719 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
>   14:04:21,720 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
>   14:04:21,720 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
>   14:04:21,720 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,720 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   14:04:21,720 +0000 INFO  [stdout] (default task-22)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am using the following versions:

Artifactory : 2.4.6

Jackson(databind,annotations,core) : 2.4.6

Comment: please post the pom/gradle build files you're using in your web app

Comment: It is for sure a dependency problem. As @zero01alpha mentioned, let's try to find the problematic dependency. Which build tool are you using?

Comment: @zero01alpha its a huge project that imports a lot of other auxiliary projects. I'm providing the dependency hierarchy present in my project. Hope that works :

artifactory-java-client-services : 2.3.5
jackson-databind : 2.4.6
jackson-core : 2.4.6
jackson-annotations : 2.4.6
jackson-mapper-asl : 1.9.12
jackson-core-asl:1.9.12

Comment: @JBaruch i'm using maven. I've provided the dependency hierarchy in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using at least version 2.4.4 of jackson-databind. `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.addMixin(Class<?>, Class<?>)`does not exist in versions below that.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit:** I misread a previous comment, which makes this answer incorrect. Leaving it here for now and will edit once we figure it out

Comment: I'm using 2.4.6 version already. My code works when i run it in a separate mains function but it stops working when i use it in my project at the service layer

Comment: oops, I misread your comment as using version 2.3.5 of databind. Well my best guess is that somewhere in your big multi tiered project a dependency for a lower version of jackson is getting pulled in and trumping the one youre using. We really need to see the entire projects dependencies to help you